# Взаимодействие приложения C++ MFC с базой данных посредством ActiveX Data Objects

Tags: c++, база-данных, visual-studio-2017, mfc

Я пишу простейшее приложение с использованием библиотеки MFC. Нужно чтобы по нажатию кнопки оно редактировало базу данных, например добавляло новую запись. Подключаться к бд нужно используя провайдер OLE DB Provider for Microsoft Jet.

По нажатию кнопки выполняю следующий код:

`CDaoDatabase db;
db.Open((LPCTSTR) "Northwind.mdb", FALSE, FALSE);`

Вылетает ошибка "Недопустимое имя файла". Пробовал и указывать полный путь к файлу и добавлять файл в папку с cpp.
Просьба наставить на правильный путь для решения этой тривиальной задачи. До этого с MFC и даже Visual Strudio не работал, просьба выражаться проще))

Comment: MFC устарел и он ужастен. А еще с MDB помню было нужно какое-то злое непонятное шаманство...

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка при преобразовании типа (LPCTSTR), вместо этого нужно преобразовывать так

```
db.Open((CString) "Northwind.mdb", FALSE, FALSE);
```

Comment: Уточню, что можно было посмотреть дебаггером на то, что получается после преобразования типа (белеберда), то вопрос сразу бы снялся.